# invalid pseudo-element or pseudo-class

Tags: css, validation

My css page validated with no errors around a month ago, and I have not edited the lines of code I am getting errors for.

```
form input:required:focus{
    border: 3px solid red;
}

form input:invalid{
    border: 3px solid grey;
}
```

The errors I get are:
"Unknown pseudo-element or pseudo-class :required" and "Unknown pseudo-element or pseudo-class :invalid".  I am validating for CSS Level 3.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `:required` and the `:invalid` pseudo-classes are part of the [CSS Selectors Level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#required-pseudo) (so you can't validate them using CSS3 validator).

Even though they only part of Level 4, most browsers already implement them - Chrome/Firefox/IE(>=10)/Opera(>=10)/Safari(>=5).